# Having problem pass data with curl into established mlflow models

Tags: python, curl, mlflow

I am following the mlflow documentations-saving and serving models(https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/quickstart.html ), and came across a problem while trying to passing data into established models.

command：

python sklearn_logistic_regression/train.py

mlflow models serve -m runs:/<RUN_ID>/model

**curl -d '{"columns":["x"], "data":[[1], [-1]]}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json; format=pandas-split' -X POST localhost:5000/invocations**

error: This predictor only supports the following content types, ['text/csv', 'application/json', 'application/json; format=pandas-records', 'application/json; format=pandas-split', 'application/json-numpy-split']. Got 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.curl:

Comment: it's interesting. if I execute your command against `nc -l localhost 5000`, I see all headers set correctly

Comment: what version of curl do you have? execute `curl --version`

Comment: and what version of MLflow?

Comment: curl 7.55.1 (Windows) libcurl/7.55.1 WinSSL

Comment: mlflow, version 1.16.0

Answer (score 1):

Changing the quotation marks from `'` to `"` solved it for me:

`curl -d "{\"columns\":[0],\"index\":[0,1],\"data\":[[1],[-1]]}" -H "Content-Type: application/json"  localhost:5000/invocations`